# Remove css/html from the bundle after it has been required and processed by webpack

Tags: assets, es6-modules, webpack-5, css-loader

I am developing one node package myself to be able to publish it to node registry and i am using webpack for bundling using ES-6 syntax.

I am using css-loader in modules inside rules configuration provided by webpack, however i only need whole content of css and not anything else. So i have configured css-loader like this.

```
module.exports = {
  //devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer']
    }),

  ],
  entry: {
    index: { import: './src/js/index.js', filename: "./js/[name].js" },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    filename: "./js/[name].js",
  },

  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        type: 'asset/source',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              exportType: "css-style-sheet"
            }
          }
        ],

        //use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],

      },

      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "fonts")],
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'fonts/[name][ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "images")],
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  snapshot: {
    managedPaths: [],
  }
}
```

and in the other javascript modules when i need css, i am importing them and processing for adding them to shadow dom. I am using `exportType` configuration of `css-loader` to be able to export as `CSSStyleSheet` object available in browser's document interface.

```
import mainSheet from '../dist/css/main.css' assert { type: 'css' };
import customSheet from '../dist/css/custom.css' assert { type: 'css' };

export default function(shadowRoot) {
    shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [mainSheet,customSheet];
}
```

This is all ok but once style has been processed and adopted by shadow dom i want to remove those styles from my bundle to reduce it;s size as there are almost more than half portion has been occupied by css itself thus making my main index.js file almost 6 MB.

I am also using html as an asset/source which does kind of same thing giving me the raw html from the file which i use as a component html.not sure if this is also present in js.

I have this question.

How to remove those other extra resources like css and html from the bundle after they are processed by the module and returned and successfully used where imported?

or is it that they will be always present in bundle as they are imported as a module and webpack creates seperate module (e.g. `__webpack__module`) inside bundled file  to get them from that bundle?

Comment: Why are you importing from `dist`? Have you considered code-splitting to make multiple, smaller bundles?

Comment: @morganney I am using scss in my package and i have used bootstrap scss and on top of it many other modifications in variables of bootstrap and then final two files in dist so i can't bundle css files in this case. I just need all the css available when writing html. css is huge and i don;t want to create bundle which will take lot of time for now.

Comment: @morganney Also, css sourcemaps are not working inside shadow dom and i am kind of stuck to indentify scss files from constructed stylesheet. This is also one more productivity breaker.